# Excel 2013 PowerPivot Table - Many Fact Tables along with a Calculated Field

Tags: excel, calculated-columns, powerpivot, calculated-field

I am pretty new on creating POWERPIVOT tables. I have searched for a bit of time now to resolve this problem but I have been unsuccessful so far. Here is my problem. As you can see below, I have created a POWERPIVOT table in Excel 2013 that is composed of two FACT tables, which are based on: 1) a sheet where the clients can insert initial budget entries; and, 2) another sheet where the clients can insert the post-initial budget entries. Also, a DIMENSION table has been added to the combination in order to add the following relationships:

[image]

Based on these relationships, I have clicked on Insert a PivotTable to create the following POWERPIVOT table that will be used to display the Initial Budget and Adjustments entries for analysis purposes. However, this table does not give me the total of both columns. I have thought that a calculated field would make it happen but this is where I am stucked as nothing let me sum the two columns like I was used to do with regular pivot tables in Excel 2007. The calculation of the two columns would logically equal the Current Budget as shown attached.

Thank you for your help on this.

[image]

Comment: you are welcome. I would appreciate if you can mark my answer as "accepted".

Comment: Where do I go to mark it?

Answer (score 0):

With Power Pivot you don't use the calculated field feature of pivot table.
You have to put a measure in your data Modell, which you can then add in the value part of the PT. Relationships alone are not enough.

```
currentBudget := CALCULATE (
    SUM ( fInitialBudget[Initial Budget] ) + SUM ( fAdjustement[Adjustements] )
)
```

if you are new with Power Pivot, I warmly recommend the book of Rob Collie ["DAX Formulas for Power Pivot"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1615470158). I got a very good introduction of the PP capability with it. The 2nd Edition is on the way.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the measure that you provided me and it works perfectly. However, I added another dimendion to map the organization. This site is awesome.